# Ubuntu compile Vala for Windows

Tags: ubuntu, compilation, gtk, vala

I've coded a little tool with vala + gtk.
Now i want to compile it as an executable for windows.
Does someone know how this works?
i'm using ubuntu 15.04 64bit

Comment: How are you compiling it? What are its dependencies?

Comment: You basically pass --cc=yourcrosscompiler see here for a tutorial: http://www.tarnyko.net/en/?q=node/15